# GroupByKey on an object using Dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm writing a simple python pipeline via apache-beam to aggregate users votes.

In input, I have comma-separated lines like this:

```
pollA,answerB
pollA,answerC
pollB,answerA
pollB,answerB
pollC,answerE
pollA,answerB
```

Next, I'm using a ParDo function to convert each line into an object like that:

**Output:**

```
{
  pollId: pollA,
  answerId: answerB,
  votes: 1
}
```

**Function:**

```
class Split(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element):
        pollId, answerId = element.split(",")

        return [{
            'pollId': pollId,
            'answerId': answerId,
            'votes': 1
        }]
```

Now, let's say I got 3 **answerB**, I'd like to group them by answerId and count them to output something like that:

```
{
  pollId: pollA,
  answerId: answerB,
  votes: 3
}
```

I'm new to python and apache-beam so i'd appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer would be to realize that each of your records could be described as:

- Key: `pollId + answerId`
- Value: `1  // The vote`

If you thus had a PCollection that are Key/Value pairs of this form you could then execute a `CombinePerKey(sum)` against that collection which would aggregate all the items with the same key summing their values giving you a new PCollection that is composed of new Key/Value pairs where their values are the sums of all the records with the same `pollId` and `answerId`.

See for example the [CombinePerKey](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.12.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.CombinePerKey) Python doc for usage of this function.